# elasticsearch more_like_this with highlights

Tags: elasticsearch

So, I've got myself a small elasticsearch server and I'm trying to do the following:
1) The user searches for some keyword(s).
2) The user is shown a list of relevant results. Results are shown from the highlights, with the search word highlighted.
3) The user clicks on a result.
4) A new page shows the whole document, the keyword is highlighted among the whole document and there's a list of relevant (more_like_this) results.

My first query is as following:

```
{
"query" : 
{
    "filtered" : 
    {
        "query": {"term": {
           "text": {
              "value": "term"
           }
        }}
    }
},
"highlight":
{
    "fields":
    {
        "title" : {"number_of_fragments" : "0"},
        "text" :  {}
    },
    "pre_tags" : ["<b>"],
    "post_tags" : ["</b>"]
},
"_source" : ["title", "date", "_id"],
"from" : 0,
"size" : 10
```

}

My second query is as following (id is obviously the document id, here 1000 for example):
`{
    "query": {
        "more_like_this": 
        {
            "fields" :  ["text","title"],
            "docs": [{
                "_id" : "1000"
            }],
            "min_term_freq" : 1,
            "include" : true
        }
    },
    "_source" : [ "title", "text", "_id", "url" ],
    "from" : 0, 
    "size" : 10
}`

Is there any way to achieve what I want (have the more_like_this query highlight the search term) or is the only solution for that is to do another query for the full document highlights?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, if you change your mapping.
You need to enable term positions and offsets.

e.g.

```
"title" : {
    "type": "string",
    "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets"
}
```

And then highlighting should work as usual. I tested it with ES version 1.6.

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/10829#issuecomment-148041529